# Dynamodb Search for a value of the key in a map of an array

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS DynamoDB, and clueless here, looking to solve querying the items with the below structure

```
{
    "API_ID": "Primary_Partition_Key",
    "transactions": {
        "<FIND_THIS_KEY>": {
            "BASED_ON_THIS": "VALUE_I_KNOW"
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to find the `FIND_THIS_KEY` from the item, based on the `VALUE_I_KNOW` mapped to `BASED_ON_THIS`

The current approach (the dumbest solution) is - fetching the complete item by `API_ID` and filtering from the map by looping it. Looking for guidance on the most effective way as the computation cost is high.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index to your "BASED_ON_THIS" which will reverse the default behaviour (you value will become your key and vice versa), so it will be efficient. Then just query the index with "BASED_ON_THIS" being the hash key and use "VALUE_I_KNOW" as a value.

Indexes will not have a unique primary key constraint and you need to be careful with hot partitions (the "BASED_ON_THIS" values to be as different as possible). So just things to keep in mind, but otherwise the index will solve your querying efficiency problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but, I believe dynamodb will not allow to create indexes on map or list attributes.

Comment: ok, got it now. You need a different table "Transactions", where you can store all transaction data and query that.